# Starting an activity from service

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I am using a service in Android, which starts an activity after a set period of time.
This is my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, PopupActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

The problem is, that if my app is running in the background (is paused), and the service starts the PopupActivity, the app running in the background is also started. 
I don't want that behaviour, is there a way to disable this, so that only my PopupActivity is shown?

Comment: **"I am using a service in Android, which starts an activity after a set period of time."** - NEVER do this. If I installed an app which did this sort of thing and pushed an `Activity` in my face when I was in the middle of playing a game, answering an SMS or email etc I'd uninstall that app straight away. Use a `Notification` and give the user the option to open your popup or not.

Comment: @Squonk Okay, I tried doing that, please see the relevant post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22793443/click-on-notification-doesnt-start-activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, in Android all the building components(including activities) live within an application context, there's no way of showing your activity without starting also your application context, it goes against the nature of Android, is like trying to start a car without starting the engine :P(couldn't think on a better example), it doesn't make any sense...

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable to define if your app is "Paused" to avoid starting the activity

```
private boolean isPaused = false;
```

if your app is paused, then isPaused = true;

```
  @Override
        protected void onPause(){
            isPaused = true;
            super.onPause();
        }
```

if your app execute `onResume()` method, then isPaused = false;

```
@Override
    protected void onResume(){
        isPaused = false;
    super.onResume();
    }
```

evaluate if isPaused isn´t false then start de activity

```
if(!isPaused){
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, PopupActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
}else{
Log.i("Activity", "Activity cannot started, app is onBackground");
}
```